# What is the maximum number of Outlook item types an Outlook folder can contain in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Is there a limit on how many item types I can have in a single folder? I need to make a folder that holds several of several different types but I don't want to start it if there is a restriction on how many I can have. Are there items that can't be in a regular folder and how many of each can be used?

Comment: If there is a limit, it'll most likely be a total object limit, regardless of the type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the maximum number of messages I can store in a folder in Microsoft Outlook?](http://superuser.com/questions/251288/whats-the-maximum-number-of-messages-i-can-store-in-a-folder-in-microsoft-outloo)

Comment: I need to know if the type changes the capacity or if there are items that cannot go into a personal folder.